# Regex: must start with a letter or a number but the rest can be anything

Tags: php, regex, perl

I am trying to construct a pattern in order to use in validation.

My goal is to have the first character to be a letter or a number, the rest anyhing.

i.ex:

1. A'r4nd0m!
2. 9!h3ll0.
3. b1llin6s

I thought of: `[a-zA-Z0-9_/][.*]++`

What would be the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: A letter or a number is `[\pL\pN]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I’ve commented, a letter or a number is `[\pL\pN]`.  Therefore a string beginning with one of those would match the pattern

```
/^[\pL\pN]/
```

Comment: Thank you. Why the slashes at the beginning and in the end?

Comment: @Phil The slashes are just delimiting the pattern. They are not meant to be part of it. If you’re stuck with PHP, you’ll have to do fancier things to make this right work on arbitrary character data, like writing a `/u` at the end. Perl of course has no such bug.

Comment: Thank you. Since I need all the possible international chars., I am employing you way. However, it using ^ for the first char doesn't seem to work with Kohana's URI system so I ended up having: [\pL\pN].*

Comment: @Phil That's a brilliant plan, removing `^`. So, does your string check the first character in your string now?

Comment: @TMZ, surprisingly, yes, in this case, Kohana's URI mechanism does check it just the way I needed. What I'm using is, as I said: [\pL\pN].*
And it works!

Comment: @TMZ It is peculiar, but in some libraries there are implicit anchors supplied. I believe that Python’s normal match function supplies a leading `^` and that Java’s match function supplies both a `^` and a `$`. These are definite gotchas for people coming from more unadorned backgrounds in pattern matching. Since only a pattern was asked for, I tried to write it generically, but one may have to make adjustments based on the target language, library, and actual function call used.

Comment: @ Phil TMZ? That's one out of three correct. I am beginning to grasp the nature of your difficulties with regexes... @tchrist That is peculiar indeed.

Comment: @Phil There should have been a smiley in there. ;) My bad.

Answer (score 4):

If the first number is a number or letter, you have `^[A-Za-z0-9]`. (The `^` matches the beginning of the string.) For the rest to be anything, a simple `.*` will suffice, so you have `^[A-Za-z0-9].*`.

Comment: For the rest to be anything, `.*` is superfluous.

Comment: @tchrist Maybe so, but it's not wrong. If you're the downvoter, I think that's a little harsh. If someone else downvoted, care to explain why?

Answer (score 3):

You can trim down your regex a little:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9].*
```

Starts with letter/number, can be of any length or any characters after.

Comment: Eek! First, the trailing `.*` is utterly superfluous, and therefore misleading.  Second, a letter or a number is `[\pL\pN]`, and any time you catch yourself writing an explicit range, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You must anchor your regex at the start of the string, using `/^/`. Your character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_/]` also matches an underscore and a slash: is this what you intend? Also, `[.*]++` matches one or more dots or stars, and the trailing `+` superfluously duplicates the quantifier.

Since the remainder of the string can be "anything" there is no point in matching it, and

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]/
```

will do fine.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. It's my mistake, I do not wish to match neither an underscore nor a slash. Just numbers and letters for the first character.

Comment: @tchrist: (Is your first name Anne?!) Yes, but `\pL` and `\pN` match many more (international) characters than `[A-za-z]` and `[0-9]`, and that behaviour may not be desirable.

Comment: @Borodin The spec asked for a letter; a letter is `\pL`.  The spec asked for a number; a number is `\pN`.  I’m trying to stamp out dumb typewriter-mentalities from the 19th century.  There is no such thing as an international character.

Comment: @tchrist: the spec also proposed a simple ASCII alphanumeric match; keep your (19th-century typewriter?) mission to yourself. You know very well that *international* is used for *multi-national* and even *foreign*, especially in your country. You are picking fault unecessarily and I am going to ignore you